# How to check internet connectivity continuously in background while android application running

Tags: android

I want to check internet connectivity continuously in background while my android application running. I mean from starting of the application to the end of the application. How can i do it? What should be the approach?

Comment: You can use a `service` and from there you can check is network available or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350449/how-to-check-the-internet-connection-periodically-in-whole-application/10350511#10350511 please see this one.

Comment: please refere to my answer [here][1] 

Hope that helps 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21250768/957654

Comment: Thanks Bibek, user3110424, Amrola for answering...will let you know what works for me...

Answer (score 6):

I know I am late to answer this Question.
But here is a way to monitor the Network Connection Continuously in an Activity/Fragment.

We will use Network Callback to monitor our connection in an Activity/Fragment

first, declare two variable in class

```
// to check if we are connected to Network
boolean isConnected = true;

// to check if we are monitoring Network
private boolean monitoringConnectivity = false;
```

Next, We will write the Network Callback Method

```
private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback connectivityCallback
            = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
            isConnected = true;
            LogUtility.LOGD(TAG, "INTERNET CONNECTED");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Network network) {
            isConnected = false;
            LogUtility.LOGD(TAG, "INTERNET LOST");
        }
    };
```

Now Since we have written our Callback we will Now write a method which will monitor our Network Connection, and in this method, we will register our NetworkCallback.

```
// Method to check network connectivity in Main Activity
    private void checkConnectivity() {
        // here we are getting the connectivity service from connectivity manager
        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(
                Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Getting network Info
        // give Network Access Permission in Manifest
        final NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // isConnected is a boolean variable
        // here we check if network is connected or is getting connected
        isConnected = activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (!isConnected) {
            // SHOW ANY ACTION YOU WANT TO SHOW
            // WHEN WE ARE NOT CONNECTED TO INTERNET/NETWORK
            LogUtility.LOGD(TAG, " NO NETWORK!");
// if Network is not connected we will register a network callback to  monitor network
            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(
                    new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                            .build(), connectivityCallback);
            monitoringConnectivity = true;
        }

    }
```

All our work is almost finished we just need to call our checkConnectivity(), the method in onResume() of our Activity/Fragment

```
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkConnectivity();
    }
```

***unRegister the NetworkCallback in onPause() ,method of your Activity/Fragment ***

```
   @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // if network is being moniterd then we will unregister the network callback
        if (monitoringConnectivity) {
            final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                    = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(connectivityCallback);
            monitoringConnectivity = false;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

That's it, just add this code in which every class of your Activity/Fragment were you need to monitor the Network!.And don't forget to unregister it!!!

Comment: I noticed that when user switch network (from wifi to cellular, for example), the onAvailable() gets called first for the cellular network, then onLost() is called for the disconnected wifi network. As a result, the app will behave as if there's no network. Do you have a solution to that?

Comment: try to add some delay before executing your code in onLost() method. Delay of 5 or 10 Sec should be enough. if this doesn't help check out my library for no network connection https://github.com/vasu-bhardwaj/NoInternet.This library use observable design pattern.

Comment: I also noticed that this code won't cover the scenario when WIFI is connected but no internet available. How can we overcome from that situation anything where regular ping can be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

Create class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`, use `ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY` to get connection info.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CheckConnectivity extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

    boolean isConnected = arg1.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
    if(isConnected){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connection Lost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }
 }
```

Add this permission in mainfest too

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Bad idead! Use service to do the network checking then pull it from BroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 1):

In Activity or fragment

```
public static final String BROADCAST = "checkinternet";
IntentFilter intentFilter;
```

inside oncreate

```
   intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
   intentFilter.addAction(BROADCAST);
   Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,Networkservice.class);
   startService(serviceIntent);
   if (Networkservice.isOnline(getApplicationContext())){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }else
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

outside oncreate

```
 public BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(BROADCAST)){
            if (intent.getStringExtra("online_status").equals("true")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("data","true");
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("data", "false");
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);
}
```

//class

```
public class Networkservice extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handler.post(perioud);
    return START_STICKY;
}
public static boolean isOnline(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nf=cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (nf!=null&&nf.isConnectedOrConnecting())
        return true;
        else
            return false;
}
Handler handler=new Handler();
private Runnable perioud =new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(perioud,1*1000- SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()%1000);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MainActivity.BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra("online_status",""+isOnline(Networkservice.this));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**ConnectivityObserver.kt:**

```
package com.example.checkInternet

import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

interface ConnectivityObserver {

    fun observe(): Flow<Status>

    enum class Status {
        Available, Unavailable, Losing, Lost
    }
}
```

**NetworkConnectivityObserver.kt:**

```
package com.example.checkInternet

import android.content.Context
import android.net.*
import android.os.Build
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.awaitClose
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.callbackFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.distinctUntilChanged
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class NetworkConnectivityObserver(
    context: Context,
): ConnectivityObserver {

    private val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    private val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .build()

    override fun observe(): Flow<ConnectivityObserver.Status> {
        return callbackFlow {
            val callback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                    super.onAvailable(network)
                    launch { send(ConnectivityObserver.Status.Available) }
                }

                override fun onLosing(network: Network, maxMsToLive: Int) {
                    super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive)
                    launch { send(ConnectivityObserver.Status.Losing) }
                }

                override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                    super.onLost(network)
                    launch { send(ConnectivityObserver.Status.Lost) }
                }

                override fun onUnavailable() {
                    super.onUnavailable()
                    launch { send(ConnectivityObserver.Status.Unavailable) }
                }
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(callback)
            }else{
                connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, callback)
            }
            awaitClose {
                connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(callback)
            }
        }.distinctUntilChanged()
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.checkInternet

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.example.checkInternet.ConnectivityObserver
import com.example.checkInternet.NetworkConnectivityObserver
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val connectivityObserver : NetworkConnectivityObserver by lazy {
        NetworkConnectivityObserver(this)
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main)

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            connectivityObserver.observe().collect {
                when (it) {
                    ConnectivityObserver.Status.Available -> {
                      Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Network Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                    ConnectivityObserver.Status.Unavailable -> {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Network Unavailable",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                    ConnectivityObserver.Status.Losing -> {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Network Losing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                    ConnectivityObserver.Status.Lost -> {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Network Lost",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android system already does that for you. Instead of constantly polling the phone for the network state, register `BroadcastReceiver`s for WiFi and network state changes and process the `Intent`s sent by the system when the WiFi or network state changes.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed) for more information on this.

Once you register your `BroadcastReceiver`, the network state change listening will happen in the background (in the OS) and an `Intent` will be sent to your receivers on the UI thread (most likely) when the network state changes. If you want to receive the `Intent`s on a background thread, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674518/does-broadcastreceiver-onreceive-always-run-in-the-ui-thread) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this service Class. Just set the time interval in seconds and the url to ping:

[Android Check Internet Connection](https://github.com/oscarjiv91/Android-Check-Internet-Connection)

Just remember to add the service to the Manifest file, and add the permissions

Answer (score 0):

To check internet connectivity simply register the broadcast for **CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE** and **WIFI_STATE_CHANGED**. So whenever internet is connected or disconnected  event occurs onReceive method of our BroadcastReceiver gets called where we can write our logic.

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <receiver
            android:name="NetworkChangeReceiver"
            android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

In NetworkChangeReceiver class.

```
 public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    
            int status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
            if ("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE".equals(intent.getAction())) {
                if (status == NetworkUtil.NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED) {
                 
                  //write code for internet is disconnected...

                } else {

                   //write code for internet is connected...

                }
           }
        }
    }
```

To check the status of internet.

```
 public class NetworkUtil {
    public static final int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;
        public static final int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
        public static final int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
        public static final int NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED = 3;
        public static final int NETWORK_STATUS_WIFI = 4;
        public static final int NETWORK_STATUS_MOBILE = 5;
    
        public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (null != activeNetwork) {
                if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                    return TYPE_WIFI;
    
                if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    return TYPE_MOBILE;
            } 
            return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
        }
    
        public static int getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
            int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
            int status = 0;
            if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
                status = NETWORK_STATUS_WIFI;
            } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                status = NETWORK_STATUS_MOBILE;
            } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
                status = NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED;
            }
            return status;
        }
    }
```