# Kotlin Monitoring Network connection returns "available" when disconnecting WIFI

Tags: android, kotlin

I have followed [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254555/how-to-check-internet-connectivity-continuously-in-background-while-android-appl) to create a method where I continuously monitor internet connection.

If WIFI is connected, I get the message "Network Available".

If I disconnect the connection, I get "Netowrk lost", all good. Then Immediately, I get "network available" notification, as long as a hotsopot is nearby (even if wifi is turned disconnected)

How can I modify the solution here, for SDK 23 to 29 so that I get

- a single "network lost but possible to connect" notification, once wifi is disconnected,
- a single "no network" is wifi is off
- and a single "network unavailable" if hotspot is off, but wifi is on.

Thank you. Please note, any other combination of notifications showing the availability/unavailability of internet will be considered as well as long as I dont have to ping google or a fixed set of servers.