# how to still connected and re-connect if the connection fail

Tags: java, android, sockets

### I have a Service that run all the time (even when my main application is not active).

the application establish connection and pass Streams to the service.
then the service read these streams all the time (every second), and notify me if it receive data to the streams.

*My Question:*

how to still connected, I mean if I lose the connection how to re-establish it.
(i.e losing wifi and mobile data and get them later), I want the Service to keep trying to connect all the time  until it find internet connection available (wifi for example).

tow scenarios:

1) A.connection fail because of a Server failure  B.the Service trying to re-establish the connection. C. the server got online. D. the service success to connect.

2)A. connection fail because of Wifi/mobile-data  not available. B.the Service trying to re-establish the connection. C. there is a Data (wifi/mobile) available now.  D. the service success to connect.

how to do that?
point: like Whatsapp service keeping connected even after losing internet connection and retrieve it.

My Service Code:

```
public class seekNet extends Service {


    private Message newMessageArrived = new Message();

    Intent intent1;
    private final IBinder Ibinder = new MyBinder();


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    this.intent1=intent;

        return Ibinder;
    }
    boolean streamsOK=true;
    boolean SoktOK=true;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         streamsOK=true;
         SoktOK=true;
        Timer t_s = new Timer();
        t_s.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Message connected =new Message();
                connected.setBody("Is the connection on?");
                connected.type=402;

                try {
                    SendRandom.ObjectOutServerchtStstus.writeUnshared(connected);
                 }catch (StreamCorruptedException stream){
                    streamsOK=false;

            }catch (SocketException e) {
                    SoktOK=false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IOException io){
                    io.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    if((SendRandom.ObjectInServerchtStstus.readUnshared())==null)
                        Log.d("SOMAA","Connection Down1");
                }catch (SocketException e){

                    Log.d("SOMAA","Connection Down2");
                }catch (StreamCorruptedException stream){
                    Log.d("SOMAA","Connection to service Down");

                }


                catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        },10,100);

//-------| you can ignore the above part, it's may attempt and not complete |--

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    newMessageArrived = (Message) SendRandom.ObjectInServercht.readUnshared();
                }catch (StreamCorruptedException stream){
                    Log.d("SOMAA","Connection to service Down2");
                    return;
                }catch (SocketException so)
                {  Log.d("SOMAA","Connection to service Down2 Socket error");
                    return;}
                catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(NullPointerException nu){
                nu.printStackTrace();
            }
                 if ( newMessageArrived!= null) {

                        Intent messagesI = new Intent("Messages");
                        messagesI.putExtra("body", newMessageArrived.getBody());
                        messagesI.putExtra("From", newMessageArrived.getFrom());
                        messagesI.putExtra("To", newMessageArrived.getTo());
                        messagesI.putExtra("toGender", newMessageArrived.getTogender());
                        messagesI.putExtra("SenderGender", newMessageArrived.my_gender);
                        messagesI.putExtra("msgType", newMessageArrived.type);
                        messagesI.putExtra("url", newMessageArrived.url);
                        messagesI.putExtra("SenderID", newMessageArrived.userID);
                        messagesI.putExtra("Time", newMessageArrived.getTime());
                        messagesI.putExtra("msgId", newMessageArrived.msgID);
                        messagesI.setAction("com.esmaeel.incomIM");
                        if(newMessageArrived.type==MessageType.TextMessage)
                        {
                         pushNotification(newMessageArrived);
                        }
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcastSync(messagesI);
                     newMessageArrived=null;
                    }

                try{ // check the connection
            SendRandom.ObjectOutServercht.writeUnshared(new Message());
                }catch (StreamCorruptedException st){
                    Log.d("SOMAA","Stream currpted");
                   streamsOK=false;
                    if(SendRandom.sktChat.isClosed())
                    { SoktOK=false;
                    Log.d("SOMAA","Socket closed!!");
                    }

                }catch (SocketException so){
                    Log.d("SOMAA","socket error "+ so.getMessage());
                    SendRandom.isConnectedSucess=false;
                    SoktOK=false;
                }catch (IOException ex){
                    Log.d("SOMAA","IO error");
                }
if(SoktOK&&!streamsOK){

    try {
        Log.d("SOMAA","1. Trying to Fix the streams");

        SendRandom.ObjectOutServercht = new ObjectOutputStream( SendRandom.sktChat.getOutputStream());
        SendRandom.ObjectInServercht = new ObjectInputStream( SendRandom.sktChat.getInputStream());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("SOMAA","2. connot Fix the streams");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
 if(!SoktOK){
     Log.d("SOMAA","no socket!, Will call conectNet0().execute();");//conectNet0()=Async class that establish connection.

     new conectNet0().execute();
     Log.d("SOMAA"," conectNet0().execute(); called!");

 }

            }
        }, 10, 100);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {

        seekNet getService() {
        return seekNet.this;
        }
    }

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("SOMAA", "OnCreate");
        newMessageArrived.url = "temp";
        newMessageArrived.setTogender("Temp");
        newMessageArrived.my_gender = "Temp";
        newMessageArrived.type = 9;
        newMessageArrived.userID = "temp";
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override

    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("SOMAA", "onDestroy Service");
    }

    public void pushNotification(Message arrivedMSG) {
        String msgbdy = arrivedMSG.getBody();



        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent1, 0);

        // build notification
        Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("new message")
                .setContentText("Strange: "+ msgbdy)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.notify, msgbdy, pIntent)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // hide the notification after its selected
        n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: please proivde source code of your service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refere to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21250768/957654)  , where it shows how you can monitor the WIFI when its connected or not , and there you can start your service . :

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 

    boolean isConnected = wifi != null &&   
                wifi.isConnected() ;

    if (isConnected ) {
        // Do something

        Log.d("Netowk Available ", "Flag No 1");
    }else {
       Log.d("Netowk not available  Available ", "Flag No 2");

     }
  }
}
```

and use an AlarmManager to start the service every X second like the follwoing :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// Start every 30 seconds
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
```

Hope that helps .

Comment: thanks, the answer is about detecting the Wifi status, but I want to know every particular time if the connection is on!, after thet (by ur answer) I look for the reason, and the reconnect.
the parts the unanswered: 
1. "to know every particular time if the connection is on!"
2. to get the reason of the disconnecting...
3. trying to re- connect!

Comment: through the BroadcastReceiver you will get notify every time the wifi status change , so there you know when you are connected or disconnected

Comment: Oh I didn't tell, I am the owner of the server, so, if the server fail??? and the wifi on??? :)) , ur answer helped me much, but it's not exactly what I need!

Comment: tell me what you want more so i could improve my answer

Comment: to detect the disconnection!, and retrieve the connection, not matter about the reason of disconnection..

Comment: i added the code for disconnection and retrieve the connection is already there

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution: 
Detect "half open Connection"
 http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html
when I detect that I set a flag to my application to try re-connect until it success..and set that flag to connected mode. (the flag is simple boolean variable)